# Flipping child object of player isnt working propely

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I have a particle system attached to the player in my 2d game, the players scale is inverted when hes is facing right left and im keep track of this with a bool isFacingRight. When the player is facing right left i also want to particle system to flip, im doing this with a rotate function because the particle system has a specific shape, so inverting it dosent work. When i face right this works, but when i face left the particles shoot downwards, but when i turn back to the right before the animation finishes the particels still shoot to the left but now straight. I only want the particels to shoot out at two angels, not three, HELP!!

```
if(!isFacingRight )
 {
     particles.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 165);
 }
 else 
 {
     particles.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
 }
 particles.Play();

if((!isFacingRight && horizontal >0f) || (isFacingRight && horizontal < 0f)) 
{
    isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
    Vector3 localScale = transform.localScale;
    localScale.x *= -1f;
    transform.localScale = localScale;
}
```

Comment: try rotating around the y axis instead of the z axis.

Answer (score 0):

if your character is flipping so will its child. So flipping it back with `localScale.x *= -1f;` is great but you might be reversing it with `transform.localScale = localScale;` depending on the `localScale.x` variable. Also 165 degrees do slightly point to down you probably meant 180 there. Here is 0, 165 and 180 degrees (in this order)

[image: 0 degrees] [image: 165 degrees] [image: 180 degrees]